# Turn object instance that uses $.extend into proper jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I made some jquery plugins, but they are not plugins per se as they are not called like a regular jquery plugin, but rather you have to make a new instance of the object, add the main div as the first argument and the configuration object literal as the second argument.

It all works fine for me, but I would like to turn it into a real jquery plugin.

Take a look at the following code:

CSS:

```
p {
    color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="p1"><p>text 1</p></div>
<div class="p2"><p>text 2</p></div>
<div class="p3"><p>text 3</p></div>
```

JS/jQuery:

```
function changeColor() {
    var self = this;

    this.config = {
        color: 'green'
    };

};

changeColor.prototype.init = function(elem, config) {
    var self = this;

    this.elem = elem;

    $.extend(this.config, config);

    self.blueColor();
};

changeColor.prototype.blueColor = function() {
    var self = this;

    $(self.elem + ' p').css('color', self.config.color);
};


(function() {
// create new instances 
    var c1 = new changeColor();
    c1.init('.p1', {
        color: 'blue'
    });


    var c2 = new changeColor();
    c2.init('.p3', {
        color: 'yellow'
    });

})();
```

What I want is to be able to call my plugin any number of times in the same page (targetting different divs), but using the normal jquery plugin way.

So, instead of the following where I have to initiate the "plugin" by doing:

```
var c1 = new changeColor();
    c1.init('.p1', {
        color: 'blue'
    });
```

I want to do it using:

```
$('.p1').init({color:'blue'});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :** jQuery Widget Factory

see http://jqueryui.com/widget/

**Solution 2 :**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.testFunction = function() {
        console.log('test');        
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').testFunction(); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jSwhN/

I personaly use the Widget Factory but the solution 2 is convenient.